# Python: Modularized Programming to find Circumference, Diameter, and Area from circles Radius

Tags: python

I have to create a modularized program that can find out the Diameter, Circumference, and Area of a circles radius. I'm sure many of you can notice I kind of winged this from a example given from my teacher. Instead of people pointing out the fact that I coded this wrong could you please give me reasons for what I should do so I can better understand this concept. Thanks

```
def main():
    Radius = 0
    Diameter = 0
    Circumference = 0
    Area = 0


    Radius = GetRadius(Radius)
    Diameter = SetDiameter(Radius,Diameter)
    Circumference = SetCircumference(Radius,Circumference)
    Area = SetArea(Radius,Area)
    ShowResults(Radius,Diameter,Circumference,Area)


def GetRadius(myradius):
    myradius = float(input("Enter your radius: "))
    return myradius

def SetDiameter(myradius,mydiameter):
    mydiameter = myradius * 2
    return mydiameter

def SetCircumference(myradius,mycircumference):
    PIE = 3.14159
    mycircumference = 2 * PIE * myradius
    return mycircumference

def SetArea(myradius,myarea):
    PIE = 3.14159
    myarea = PIE * myradius ^ 2
    return myarea

def ShowResults(Radius,Diameter,Circumference,Area):
    print("The Diameter is",mydiameter)
    print("The Circumference is",mycircumference)
    print("The Area is",myarea)

main()
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: When posting a question, please keep the following in mind: If the code works, but you're looking for someone else's opinion on how to possibly make it better, use codereview as Mark has pointed out above. If the code does NOT work, and you need help figuring out why it isn't working, then show an example of the inputs/outputs that seem incorrect, and what you expected the correct output to be. Right now, the way your question is worded, I'm not sure if you're looking to see how to improve correct code or find what's wrong with incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

`myarea = PIE * myradius ^ 2`

In Python, the exponentiation operator is `**`.

`myarea = PIE * myradius ** 2`

(In fact, don't expect ^ to ever be exponentiation in a programming language. It is usually the bitwise xor operator.)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I suggest is you remove the parameters you want to return from the argument lists:

```
def SetDiameter(myradius,mydiameter):
    mydiameter = myradius * 2
    return mydiameter
```

Should be

```
def SetDiameter(myradius):
    mydiameter = myradius * 2
    return mydiameter
```

If you return the value from the function you don't need to include it in the argument list. This important in understanding how python works.

I don't know what your original assignment is, but the best way to improve your skills and this short program would probably be to add a circle class. You should definitely read this:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html